# Its Possible to Resize/Move sda3(ext4 /)?

Tags: 20.04, partitioning

i have tried move unallocated partition to sda3(ext4/) on live CD but failed. Is it possible to resize it or just re install ? Can you give me some information on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Unallocated space is not a partition.

Comment: You MSDOS partitioning allows only four primary partitions, which you have. you need to make the extended partition either larger or smaller, depending if you want sda3 to be a primary, delete empty sda5 which is in the way, then move sda3 left, a slow, dangerous operation if interrupted, so backup first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the space to sda3 you need to:
1) move your swap to the left. ( So the unallocated space is on the right. )
2) decrease your extended partition with the amount of the unallocated space. ( So your unallocated space becomes part of a primary partition. )
3) Move sda3 to the left. ( so the unallocated space is located on the right side of sda3. )
4) Enlarge sda3 with the amount of unallocated space.
As usual, make backups of important files first ( preferably on another disk ).